# How to make an HTML table fixed width when resize page

Tags: html, html-table

My HTML table width is unknown, and I want to make it fixed width for each td

`table-layout=fixed` is working if I set the width of table. However my situation is that the table width is unknown:

```
<table style="border:solid 1px #333;table-layout:fixed">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:200px">200</td>
    <td style="width:300px">300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input style="width:100%"></td>
    <td><input style="width:100%"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Above example is working beautiful if my browser page width is bigger than 500px, however when I resize page, I need the tds stay at fixed with.

If there is no `input` inside td the following will work:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
  <tr>
    <td style="min-width:200px">
```

However there is an input inside td

The following is working version, each time resize td, need update table width:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed;width:500px">
  <tr>
    <td style="min-width:200px">
```

Well, I finally found it working this way: **min-width + size=1** working :)

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
  <tr>
    <td style="min-width:200px">header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input size="1"></td>
  </tr>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7nttub0b/3/

Comment: You would normally use colspan for this, but if you are needing this, you should have a fixed table size. Why do you need a fixed size column with an unknown table size? If you want to achieve this, make table 500px, colspan=2 for first column ,and colspan=3 for the second column.

Comment: You wan't fixed width on something you don't know the width of? Why?

Answer (score 2):

This might work if you want fixed sized td:

```
<table style="border:solid 1px #333;table-layout:fixed">
  <tr>
    <td style="min-width:200px">200</td>
    <td style="min-width:300px">300</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @SIDU I don't think this is your original code. see **min-width**

Comment: OK Thanks. min-width IS working with text. However my fault did not give detailed question, in the TD, there is input with 100% width, which stop the min-width of td working

Comment: sry i dont quite understand your question but is this what u want to do \

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this: `<table  style="border:solid 1px #333; table-layout:fixed" width="400">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1" width="500px">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:200px">200</td>
    <td style="width:300px">300</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes this is what i said working - but i m wondering if it is working without table width = 500px

Comment: If i set table width = 500px, each time when i resize a td, I need to adjust table width as well

Comment: you asked for the fixed width, so that i used fixed width for the table and td as well. now this table will remain the same width on all screen resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<table style="border:solid 1px #333;table-layout:auto">
   <tr>
     <td style="width:200px">200</td>
     <td style="width:300px">300</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No. i need fixed width. no 100%